# Is this an encoding issue?

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, iconv, as.date

I downloaded a text file that contains basically two columns—a date column and a contents column.

The date column was initially in the format: `mm/dd/yy h:mm:ss am/pm`. For example, one such date would be `10/16/2018 8:10:10 PM`

I wanted to get the normal date isolated. I split the text column using the `strsplit()` command and so now I have a vector with dates in the common `mm/dd/yy` format. I want to convert this using the `as.Date(x, format = '%m/%d/%y)` coommand.

I notice, however, that I get a good chunk of my character vector coming out as `NA`. I compared the `NA` values to the values surrounding it. Here is what I see:

```
normal_vector[1:3]
[1] "10/12/17" "‎10/12/17" "10/12/17"
```

**The middle one (`normal_vector[2]`) is the problem one. **

```
as.Date(normal_vector[1:3], format = "%m/%d/%y")
[1]  "2017-10-12" NA           "2017-10-12"
```

Could this be an encoding issue? I try using the `as.Date(iconv(normal_vector[1:3], to = "UTF-8"), format = "%m/%d/%y")` but it does not appear to help. Furthermore, if I inspect the encoding of the character vectors as it already is, I get the following:

```
Encoding(normal_vector[1:3])
[1] "unknown" "UTF-8"   "unknown"
```

Again, I just want to convert all three of these elements into a normal date object in R. They appear identical, and the encoding would have me think that a "UTF-8" character would be easily handled by an `as.Date()` function. What are some possible reasons that it refuses to be converted to a date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed some strange characters (three 'dots') in your second string
look at the hex `e280 8e`
[image]

`fread` from the `data.table`-package can read these text just fine...

```
data.table::fread("./temp.csv", header = FALSE)
#          V1          V2       V3
# 1: 10/12/17 â€Ž10/12/17 10/12/17
```

after reading, you can cleanse your data using some regex-magic...

```
dt <- data.table::fread("./temp.csv", header = FALSE)
#          V1          V2       V3
# 1: 10/12/17 â€Ž10/12/17 10/12/17

#strip all NON 0-9, a-z, A-z AND '/' -characters
cleaned <- as.character( gsub( "[^0-9a-zA-Z/]", "", as.matrix( dt ) ) )

as.Date( cleaned, format = "%m/%d/%y" )
# [1] "2017-10-12" "2017-10-12" "2017-10-12"
```

Comment: Woa. Thanks for catching that. You can see that just from me pasting the output from my console to the website? So cool! Welk in this case, how should I proceed? Does this mean iconv() is useless?